# prisma2 set length and column type in prisma schema

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

how can i set string(varchar) length for string type be 50 and define a column be TEXT in prisma schema, for user table i want `name` be varchar(50) and `bio` be Text column.
im creating my tables by prisma migrate save and up.

```
model User {

  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  name      String   ***** varchar 50****
  bio       String  *****TEXT ??

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following feature was added recently in [v2.17.0](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.17.0). You can specify database types in a scalar field's attributes using `@db.` followed by the desired native database type attribute specified by Prisma. For `varchar`, use the following for PostgreSQL.

```
model User {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  name      String   @db.VarChar(50)
}
```

For more database types, refer to the [Prisma Schema API docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#string).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Sqlite only supports `TEXT`. https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#sqlite

Answer (score 2):

@Griffin is correct. Additionally, your `bio` field can be left as is. Prisma sets `String` type as native database `text` types by default (only PostgreSQL & SQLite only). You can also set it explicitly regardless of the database:

```
model User {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  name      String   @db.VarChar(50)
  bio       String   @db.Text
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Sqlite only supports `TEXT`. https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#sqlite